# Selectize multiple data attributes

Tags: jquery, selectize.js

I want to use selectize for one of my project.

Is it possible to have multiple data attributes on options ?

For example, with one attribute I have :

```
<option value="{{$type['nom']}}" data-data='{"coeff":{{$type["coeff_principal"]}}}'>{{$type['nom']}}</option>
```

And :

```
    render: {
       option: function (data, escape) {
         return "<div data-coeff='" + data.coeff + "'>" + data.text + </div>"
       }
    },
```

What about multiple attributes ? If I need data-coeff and data-id ?

Thank

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you mean, your first example and your render and totally different. one has data-data the other has data-coeff. You can have any number of data-xxx that you want.

```
    render: {
       option: function (data, escape) {
         return "<div data-one='" + data.one + "' data-two='" + data.two + "' data-id='" + data.id + "' data-coeff='" + data.coeff + "'>" + data.text + </div>"
       }
    },
```

You just need to make sure your back-end returns data with those properties. `data` html attribute are just used to store values, so the user won't see them, and you can have as many as you like. Remember, `option:` is for the options in the dropdown list, `item` is for selected items. You may need to include these data attributes in your `item:...` render as well, depending on the functionality you need. Check the [docs](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md) for more info.